# Concatenating multiple string columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to join 4 columsn of a dataframe, each has a list of values which need to be joined together:

The working code is as follows:

```
def create_soup(x):
    return ' '.join(x['keywords']) + ' ' + ' '.join(x['cast']) + ' ' + x['director'] + ' ' + ' '.join(x['genres'])
df['soup'] = df.apply(create_soup, axis=1)
```

My main issue with understanding this code is that `df.apply` function works on a row of data here, why can I not use this same code with the complete dataframe in one go.

Is there any method to directly do this without the apply function?

The data is as follows:

[image]

The final line contains the output of the first movie - cast + director + keywords + genres

Comment: You may have to approach this problem using [pd.DataFrame.iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).

Comment: kindly provide sample data, with expected output

Comment: Edited the question to include it

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['soup'] = (df['keywords'].str.join(' ') + ' ' + 
              df['cast'].str.join(' ') + ' ' + 
              df['director'] + ' ' +
              df['genres'].str.join(' '))
```

Similar:

```
df['soup'] = ((df['keywords'] + df['cast']).str.join(' ') + ' ' + 
               df['director'] + ' ' +
               df['genres'].str.join(' '))
```